# Nothrow with CUDA new

Tags: memory-management, cuda

What is the best way to check for successful allocation of memory when using `new` in a kernel call with CUDA? Is there anything similar to `(nothrow)` if there isn't is there a way to continue execution of the kernel, even in the event of memory allocation failure?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that `new` is officially supported on the device-side. Moreover - to my knowledge - there is no support for exceptions on the device-side, so annotations like `nothrow` have no effect.

What you *can* do in the kernel is to call `malloc`. Upon the failure the function just returns `NULL` and you can check that normally.

Do note that

- device-side `malloc` is supported only on devices 2.0 (Fermi) and higher.
- By default you have only 8MB of heap memory. If you want to have more, you need to set the higher limit through `cudaDeviceSetLimit`.

Further reading: CUDA C Programming Guide, v.5.0, chapter B.17 - Dynamic Global Memory Allocation

---

Update: Tests have shown that `new` seems to be supported and seems to be working the same way, i.e. returning `NULL` upon failure.

Comment: 'new' is indeed supported on the device side (CUDA 2.0 and up). I figured that exceptions would not be supported, I am really looking to know if a failure in memory allocation will halt the kernel's execution in anyway. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any mention of `new` support in the programming guide. If `new` is supported, it probably calls `malloc` under the hood and probably behaves similarly - that is - returns NULL upon failure.

Comment: I see, that would make sense, thank you for your explanation!

Comment: @Twiltie - I say >maybe<. I am not sure about `new`, please test it first :)

Comment: Just ran a test for allocation of large memory using new, it does indeed return a null pointer, and failure has no effect on kernel execution (even failure on multiple threads). Thanks guys!